# PHP recursive function output

Tags: php, recursion

With the following code:

```
$array = array(
    'id' => '1',
    'parent_id' => '0',
    'name' => 'top level',
    'children' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'parent_id' => '1',
        'name' => 'second level',
        'children' => array(
            'id' => '3',
            'parent_id' => '2',
            'name' => 'third level'     
        )
    )
);

function generateFlatArray($array){

  $output .= '[select id="' . $array['id'] . '" name="' . $array['name'] . '"]';

  if(is_array($array['children'])){
    generateFlatArray($array['children']);
  }

  return $output;

}

print_r(generateFlatArray($array));
```

Why does this output:

```
[select id="1" name="top level"]
```

and not what I am expecting, which is:

```
[select id="1" name="top level"][select id="2" name="second level"][select id="3" name="third level"]
```

I hate recursion. I hate recursion. I hate recursion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not use the return value of the function, only the first `$output` is used.

```
function generateFlatArray($array){

   $output .= '[select id="' . $array['id'] . '" name="' . $array['name'] . '"]';

   if(is_array($array['children'])){
     $output .= generateFlatArray($array['children']);
   }

   return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you aren't doing anything with the return value of the recursive steps.

```
$output .= generateFlatArray($array['children']);
```

That's what I think you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have to append the output during the recursive call as well:

```
if(is_array($array['children'])){
    $output .= generateFlatArray($array['children']);
}
```